# Is it possible to have one workflow associated to more than one content type?

Tags: list, workflow, content-type, document, content

I have a subsite, where I have three document libraries. Each document library has its own content type.

I have a task workflow that I would like to run on all of the lists. My problem with creating three workflows is that the workflow is triggered programmatically and the number of lists can be increased or decreased using a custom actions page.

If a new list is added by the user I cannot edit the code to start the workflow on the new list. Thus if I have one workflow with one name I can start the workflow regardless of the list it is running on. But every list has its own content type. Is there any way to do this or a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create reusable workflow without any dependency on any Content Type.
In this way you can associate one workflow with more than one content type.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response, if i create the workflow with no dependency will i be able to lookup information in the three lists when building the workflow?

Comment: Are you using designer workflow or visual studio workflow? Do you want to lookup in same list or some other list?

Comment: i am using designer, i am fairly new to sharePoint and not very familiar with workflows built in visual studio but if it is possible to do what i am looking for in visual studio the i will do it that way. I want to look up in three lists all different lists all are the same fields but different content types and all in the same subsite.

Comment: So you can simply query list with the field name. There should not be any issue if content type is different as long as field name is same.

Comment: Okay, i will start working on that now, thank you for the quick reply's and the assistance i really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks. Do mark this as a answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: I will be sure to do so.